# (CURL, PHP) Uploading files with PUT request, How do I process this?

Tags: php, curl, upload, put

this is what i have in process.php

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$upload_data);
if (isset($upload_data)) {
   print_r($upload_data);
   exit;
}
```

this is how i query to server using curl.

```
weldan@prindu:~$ curl -X PUT -H "X-TOKEN: test123" -F filedata=@/home/weldan/Pictures/Cool-Pictures1.jpg  http://host.tld/process.php
Array
(
    [------------------------------22031b6e799c
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "filedata"; filename="Cool-Pictures1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

���
)
```

so that how i know there is uploaded file there.

current problem is, how do I process this file like $_FILES variable?

open for other way to achieve this too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $_FILES array being populated on PUT requests. That's because a PUT request will specify the file name in the url and the file content in the body. Nothing more.

You'll have to use `php://input` as you already suggested.

*upload.php*

```
<?php
/* PUT data goes to php://input */
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Then use the following curl command line:

```
curl --upload -H "X-TOKEN: test123" a.txt  http://localhost/upload.php
```

*Update after comments*: Using the --upload option should fit your needs. In difference to -X PUT together with -F, the data will be send raw and get *not* multipart/form-data encoded.. One of the hidden treasures of curl ;)

Comment: so this is how it looked like: `------------------------------7bb0791da128
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test 123

------------------------------7bb0791da128--` maybe this is why  uploaded image file cannot be viewed. it has extra strings with it.

Comment: Yes :) I realized this during my tests :) But important is the first sentence.. Its more about the nature of the HTTP protocol than a php issue. With a PUT request there can be just one file, therefore no $_FILES array. **Further note the double quotes around the -F argument. Without them it will not work**

Comment: yes. did as suggestion. what we get on server side still raw binary data i think. if i stored it as filename.txt i still see the extra string, what i want to do is.. i want to store data in temporary file so i can check it's type, in my case i want image file. so your answer was actually helpful but did not solve the problem. still figuring out what to do. thanks

Comment: @WeldanJamili You are welcome. Note.. After all, I think the PHP developer where right when decide to not populate the $_FILES array on PUT requests.. But I'm not sure if it was a *wise decision* or if they just forgot it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

The only way in your situation is to parse raw request manually (look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jas-/5c3fdc26fedd11cb9fb5))

#### Thoughts

- PUT request could be used to upload one file only (not from html upload form, but using custom request). On the server you just get raw file content and writes it into some file.
- Use PUT without files (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and parse raw request using `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_PUT);`
- Use POST to upload files (multipart/form-data).