# Curl PUT request with file upload to PHP

Tags: php, curl, upload, nginx, put

I'm trying to upload a file using HTTP PUT.
After reading a bit it seems the `$_FILES` array is only with POST and `multipart/form-data`. While with PUT, I'd need to manually read `php://input` to get the data. Both methods don't work.

I tried the following options and would appreciate any tips you might have:

```sh
curl --upload avatar.jpg http://api.test.com/user/dsadasdsa
curl -X PUT -F "filedata=@avatar.jpg" http://api.test.com/user/dsadasdsa
```

My PHP File is trying to print this but returns an empty string:

```php
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I started to think this might be an Nginx issue missing PUT DELETE support and installed nginx-extras as well as adding the following to my nginx config but this doesn't help as well unfortunately.

```sh
root /var/www/;

dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;

create_full_put_path on;
dav_access group:rw all:r;
```

Comment: *reference* http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: @Gordon - Thank you. I'm aware of that page but it only tells me what to do on the PHP side (which i'm already doing). And not really telling me what I'm doing wrong on the curl side.

Comment: Also, trying to run the exact same code from the manual just creates an empty file. So I'm pretty sure my CURL request is the wrong side.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106849/curl-php-uploading-files-with-put-request-how-do-i-process-this/15106995#15106995 please

Comment: I came from there as well... I'm starting to think the error is with Nginx needing specific installation for PUT/DELETE support and I'm gonna try that. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Added some info about the Nginx side of it but I'm still stuck ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some ideas for debugging.

Do a `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` instead of an echo. According to the [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

If you get a `bool(false)` as output, there's something wrong which makes you cannot read `php://input` - most likely a PHP issue. If you get `string(0) ""`, there's just nothing in `php://input` (anymore?), which makes it more likely that this is an nginx issue.

Also, according to the [`php://` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), you cannot use `php://input` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Are you sure you don't use that one? You could also try an HTML file if that's more familiar.

You can also check the error logs, `/var/log/nginx/error.log` by default. Also, check the HTTP response code. Is it 200? If not, is it a helpful code?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get the chance to test this yet, but your answer seems the most thorough one so far. Thanks!

Comment: @ShaiMishali please let me know if you have tested. And thanks for the rep :)

Answer (score 2):

The option -F you were using causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data (see man curl).

You can use the --data-binary option like in:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary "@avatar.jpg" http://api.test.com/user/dsadasdsa
```

The -d option is only for text and may corrupt your data.

In my tests, the following command gives the same results.

```
curl --upload "avatar.jpg" http://api.test.com/user/dsadasdsa
```

Here is my server

```
<?php
echo "request method : " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . "\n";
echo "dump files ";
var_dump($_FILES);

$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)) {
      echo $data . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx supports all http verbs (put, delete, options, etc). So you don't need any special setup in nginx for that.

The following works (I am using php5.4 server to easily test this):

Add this simple testing php script called put.php

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)) {
      echo $data . "\n";
}
```

Start a php server from the same folder of put.php:

```
php -S localhost:5000
```

Issue a PUT curl request:

```
curl -d "@/path/to/put.php" -X PUT http://localhost:5000/put.php
```

This will print the file content of put.php

[**update**]

In case you want to use php to send a curl request to a restful api site, I'd recommend [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/), with which you don't have to remember all of those curl options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a PUT request to a server and can't read from the php wrapper, make sure that:

1. you have the right PUT request. complete with the headers and stuff ([Making a PUT request with PHP and CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429675/making-a-put-request-with-php-and-curl))
2. your server accepts PUT requests.
3. your php file can read simple PUT requests first (without the upload part)

You may also want to check out the 'note' indicated in the php://input (http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). Other than that, it might be an issue on the server.

Answer (score 0):

> Both methods don't work

I've never tried implementing DAV with PHP but I can assure you that POST with file uploads works, even with nginx.

> curl --upload avatar.jpg http://api.test.com/user/dsadasdsa

I would have expected this to work - what do your logs show? Did you try with '--trace'?

> curl -X PUT -F "filedata=@avatar.jpg" http://api.test.com/user/dsadasdsa

Using the -F flag with curl means to upload a file as a POST variable, using multipart/form-data encoding - which doesn't make any sense with a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you eliminated PHP as the cause of the problem by putting a different kind of webapp behind nginx, and testing to see if it can handle PUT uploads? A very short Python Flask app will let you test PUT uploads in another language.